# How to create a context-free grammar?

Tags: context-free, compilers

I am learning compilers and I am troubled by how to create the context-free grammar of a language. Is there a method I can follow to create the context-free grammar for most language ?
I'm new to this field so the question is basic,and I hope you can help me.

Comment: This seems overly broad. "How can I create a context-free grammar for a language?" is like asking "How can I write a program to accomplish some task?"

Comment: The answer would depend on how the language is defined in the first place. You could lessen the chance that your question would be closed as too broad if you gave a simple example of what the language specification would be.

Comment: We have [a reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18524/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-context-free/) on this, but it is (naturally) very abstact. You can have a look at myriads of questions via [tag:formal-grammars+context-free].